# how to calculate the specific accumulated amount in t-sql

Tags: sql

For each row, I need to calculate the integer part from dividing by 4. For each subsequent row, we add the remainder of the division by 4 previous and current lines and look at the whole part and the remainders from dividing by 4. Consider the example below:

```
    id  val
     1  22
     2  1
     3  1
     4  2
     5  1
     6  6
     7  1
```

After dividing by 4, we look at the whole part and the remainders. For each id we add up the accumulated points until they are divided by 4:

```
    id  val wh1 rem1 wh2    rem2  RESULT(wh1+wh2)
     1   22  5   2   0      2         5
     2   1   0   1  (3/4=0) 3%4=3     0
     3   1   0   1  (4/4=1) 4%4=0     1
     4   2   0   2  (2/4=0) 2%4=2     0
     5   1   0   1  (3/4=0) 3%4=3     0
     6   7   1   2  (5/4=1) 5%4=1     2
     7   1   0   1  (2/4=0) 2%4=1     0
```

How can I get the next RESULT column with sql?

Data of project:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9e18f/2

The whole part from the division into 4 is easy, the problem is to calculate the accumulated remains for each id, and to calculate which of them will also be divided into 4

Comment: no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: why not use calculate column?

Comment: The whole part from the division into 4 is easy, the problem is to calculate the accumulated remains for each id, and to calculate which of them will also be divided into 4 @TonyDong

Comment: "Please write my code" is not a question.